# Django How to show a customized admin model

Tags: python, django

Hi I want to show a customized admin model in the admin section of Django

So far I created a test_data class like this

```
class TestData:
    @classmethod
    def get_test_data(self):
       list = []
       for x in range(0,50):
         list.append(x)

       return list
```

and I import it on to the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.test_data import TestData

class TestClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list =  TestData.get_test_data()

admin.  site.register(TestClass)
```

and this gives me an error

TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

How to fix this and show custom model in admin ? Thank you in advance

Comment: can you post the relevant stack trace ?

Comment: Don't call variables and model admin fields as `list` - you are shadowing built-in `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a `ModelAdmin` object as the first argument to `admin.site.register()`

try

```
admin.site.register(TestData, TestClass)
```

You'll also need to tell your `TestClass` what model it refers to. more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).

Comment: test class does not refer to any model in the system it consists with data takes from many models and this approach is not matching, thank you

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using `models.ModelAdmin`